# How do I save an ansible variable into a temporary file that is automatically removed at the end of playbook execution?

Tags: ansible

In order to perform some operations locally (not on the remote machine), I need to put the content of an ansible variable inside a temporary file.

Please note that I am looking for a solution that takes care of generating the temporary file to a location where it can be written (no hardcoded names) and also that takes care of the removal of the file as we do not want to leave things behind.

Comment: I just gave [an answer to a similar, more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70646926/9401096) that you might be interested in if this is still a concern.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use the [tempfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/tempfile_module.html) module, followed by either the [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) or [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) modules. Like so:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    # Create a file named ansible.{random}.config
    - tempfile:
        state:  file
        suffix: config
      register: temp_config

    # Render template content to it
    - template:
        src:  templates/configfile.j2
        dest: "{{ temp_config.path }}"
      vars:
        username: admin
```

Or if you're running it in a role:

```yaml
- tempfile:
    state:  file
    suffix: config
  register: temp_config

- copy:
    content: "{{ lookup('template', 'configfile.j2') }}"
    dest:    "{{ temp_config.path }}"
  vars:
    username: admin
```

Then just pass `temp_config.path` to whatever module you need to pass the file to.

It's not a great solution, but the alternative is writing a custom module to do it in one step.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than do it with a file, why not just [use the environment](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html)? This wan you can easily work with the variable and it will be alive through the ansible session and you can easily retrieve it in any steps or outside of them.

Answer (score 1):

Although using the shell/application environment is probably, if you specifically want to use a file to store variable data you could do something like this

```
- hosts: server1
  tasks:
  - shell: cat /etc/file.txt
    register: some_data
  - local_action: copy dest=/tmp/foo.txt content="{{some_data.stdout}}"

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - set_fact: some_data="{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/foo.txt') }}"
  - debug: var=some_data
```

As for your requirement to give the file a unique name and clean it up at the end of the play.  I'll leave that implementation to you

Comment: I find myself using temp files quite a lot because I have to call functions that take files as arguments.  I have to dump the data from a variable or template into a temporary file, use it and then tidy up.  Ansible could really do with a shorthand for that.

Comment: A shorthand could be akin to Python's `with` that creates a resource that is automatically deleted when that scope has expired.  Another method that applies only when the command is a shell command is to use bash's here files: `cat <(echo foo)` that creates a temporary file, writes foo to it, then the command line function, here cat, is called on the file path.  But that is just for shell and it's kinda pushing the problem away to a language that does treat temp files as important and valuable.